# Pine Script version 5 Condition 1 applies and if condition 2 applies check if condition 1 is still in places and enter Long or Short

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

Let's say I have condition 1 which is met several times, how can I check if condition 1 is still met when condition 2 is also met and then to perform a entry Long Position or Short Position. As an example let's say condition 1 was met at current close then condition 2 happens and check if condition 1 is still active then I want to perform  a Entry Long Position. How can I formulate this in Pine Script?
I take into consideration 3 values: Short, Mid and Long
LongCondition 1 = short crossover Long
LongCondition 2 = mid crossover Long but here I need to check that LongCondition1 is still met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your condition is something like a `crossover`, you should compare the actual values at the moment. Because `crossover` or `crossunder` will be `true` for one bar only.

For example, if your condition one is `crossover(close, ema)` and if you want to see if this cross is still valid when your condition two is `true`, check if `clsoe` is still above `ema`.

```
cond1 = close > ema
cond2 = sth else
long = cond1 and cond2
```